# Emgu cv save CircleF as a image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, geometry, emgucv

I am new to image processing, In my application , i want to save the detected circles as a new image , The following code has been used to store the detected circle.

> new CircleF(new PointF(circles[0].Center.X +
>   grayframeright_1.ROI.Left, circles[0].Center.Y +
>   grayframeright_1.ROI.Top), circles[0].Radius);

Are there any methods available in emgu cv / open cv to save the circle as a new Image?

Please help me to figure this out, Code samples would be useful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want is to have a mask that covers the area of the circle and apply this mask to the image.

For this you need a mask:

```
//img is the image you applied Hough to
Image<Gray, byte> mask = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Width, img.Height);
```

mask will be a black image. You need to draw in this image the area of the circle:

```
CvInvoke.cvCircle(mask.Ptr, center, radius, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), -1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.CV_AA, 0);
//-1 is to fill the area
```

now mask will have a white circle with center in the point `center` and radius `radius`. Doing an AND operation between the original image and this mask will copy to a new image only the points where the mask is white (where the circle is drawn).

```
Image<Bgr, byte> dest = new Image<Bgr, byte>(img.Width, img.Height);
dest = img.And(img, mask);
```

You can save dest as an usual image now

```
dest.Save("C:/wherever...");
```

If the image is too big and the circle too small, you can reduce the image size setting the image ROI before saving it to be an area around the circle:

```
dest.ROI = new Rectangle(center.X - radius, center.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by save the circleF as image? Crop the image in the area of the circle?

Comment: Basically , i want to save the circle image area CircleF variable contains ..

I am storing the HoughCircles function's detected circles in a CircleF variable. So the variable contains a round part of the image  ,CircleF iris = new CircleF(iriscoordinate, circles[0].Radius); , So i want to save the part of image in my hard disk....